# How to configure two sub-domains in apache and tomcat set up.?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, mod-proxy

How to configure two sub-domains in apache and tomcat set up.?
I already have a sub-domain pointed to the server. If the request comes with /test context it will routed to tomcat . This set up done through mod_proxy

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /test1 http://localhost:8080/test1
ProxyPassReverse /test1 http://localhost:8080/test1
SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
<Location "/admin">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

Now my problem is ..
I am going to have a another application test2 hosted in tomcat and I want to know weather it is possible to point that app to new subdomain.

example

```
sample.example.com = static site in apache
sample.example.com/test = test1 application in tomcat
newsample.example.com = test2 application in tomcat
```

Comment: What part of the [Apache HTTPD Virtual Host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) documentation is not clear to you? (Hint: `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` directives can be used inside a `<VirtualHost>`)

Comment: I have gone through the document and implemented based on that but whenever I hit the subdomain it takes me to the static files hosted in apache not to application hosted in tomcat.